# When a module has a composer dependency, should it be automatically installed when the module is installed?

Tags: 8, composer

Trying to resolve a debate - if a drupal site that is configured correctly installs a module with a composer dependency, should I expect the composer dependency to be installed automatically during the install?

The other person thinks that modules with composer dependencies have to be installed through command line to work, I think that if things were configured correctly it should happen on its own.

Does someone know how it should work?

Comment: See https://www.drupal.org/node/2404989

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you install the module with composer, yes, dependencies will be fetched. If you download the tar and put it in the site, it will not.